# HTTP Direct GET request to file vs GET from html tag

Tags: html, apache, http, server

Is there an accurate way to distinguish between a GET request directly to a file :

website.com/file.css

and a GET request to the same file but when loading a page that includes:

```
<style rel = "file.css">
```

As far as I can tell, the HTTP requests are pretty much identical.

Are there any solutions which don't involve:

Monitoring the server request logs (timing / sequence based).

Adding in GET parameters, e.g. file.css?r=dgsfgfgd

Using CSP reporting.

Comment: You can check the "Origin" or "Referrer" header from the HTTP request, if either of the header is empty it's manually requested via the browser. However, one can manually craft a request to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

I'm not too worried about people creating their own requests, more so about people opening source files directly.

In regards to origin / referrer:

Using Google Chrome, neither are set when I view the file in the above situations.

The Referrer Policy is set, and is slightly different, one no-referrer and the other no-referrer-when-downgrade, but I'm not sure if that's a reliable way to distinguish the two.

Everything else in the request is pretty much identical.